# Video and Audio recording

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am able to record video and audio using the give code below, but when I speak I can hear my own audio, like audio playback, and in the recording as well its creating problem, because of this audio playback issue, audio of recording is becoming dull, how can I resolve this audio playback issue?

```
    const videoRef = useRef(null);
    const [recording, setRecording] = useState(false);
    const [mediaStream, setMediaStream] = useState(null);
    const [mediaRecorder, setMediaRecorder] = useState(null);
    const [videoChunks, setVideoChunks] = useState([]);


  //   ------ recording functions -------
    const startRecording = async () => {
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: true,
    audio: true,
    });
    setMediaStream(stream);
    videoRef.current.srcObject = stream;

    const recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
    setMediaRecorder(recorder);

    recorder.ondataavailable = (event) => {
    if (event.data.size > 0) {
    setVideoChunks((prevChunks) => [...prevChunks, event.data]);
    }
    };

    recorder.start();
    setRecording(true);
    };

    const stopRecording = () => {
    mediaRecorder.stop();
    mediaStream.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());
    setRecording(false);
    };

    const downloadVideo = () => {
    const blob = new Blob(videoChunks, { type: "video/webm" });
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    // console.log(url)
    const a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = url;
    a.download = "recorded-video.webm";
    a.click();
    };

    useEffect(() => {
    startRecording();
    }, []);

    <video
    ref={videoRef}
    autoPlay
    style={{ transform: "scaleX(-1)" }}
    className="userVideo"
    >
    <source
    src={URL.createObjectURL(
    new Blob(videoChunks, { type: "video/webm" })
    )}
    type="video/webm"
    />
    </video>
```

Comment: Maybe set the video tag to muted?

Comment: which video tag?

Comment: The tag of the video element you have in your code?

Comment: I achieved the required result, I had to pass an attribute muted in video tag